# Meaning of Introduction

Tags: word-meaning

When I have to come up with a title for my presentation in English, I'm always confused at using "Introduction".

For example, the presentation is about the safety system of something. And I would like to talk about the brief ideas and explanation about the system.

In this situation, can I use "the Introduction to the Safety System of **” for the title of my presentation?

I looked for introduction in Longman and Oxford, and they say as follows:

> **Introduction**: 6 EXPLANATION [countable] something that explains the
>   basic facts of a subject introduction to
>   e.g.:The book is a useful introduction to British geology.[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/introduction)
>
> **Introduction**: to subject ​
>   [countable] *introduction (to something)* a book or course
>   for people beginning to study a subject
>
> e.g.: ‘An Introduction to Astronomy’
>
> It's a useful introduction to an extremely complex subject.
>   [Oxford](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/introduction?q=introduction)

But it seems like "introduction to something" is used only for the title of a course or a book.

Can I use this word for the title for my presentation to explain the brief explanation about the system?

Comment: What you are looking for, I think, is "overview".

Comment: @AIQ  That’s a good one. Thank you. Then can’t I use introduction in this case?

Comment: Well, to be honest it is not quite clear what you are asking. In your first sentence you mention "title". Are you asking if you can use the word "introduction" in your presentation title? Or are you asking if you can use "introduction" while explaining in your presentation the main ideas that you will be discussing?

Comment: the former one. So I’d like to know if I can use introduction in the presentation title.

Comment: Sure you can. Here are few examples: *"Introduction to smart security systems"*, *"Introduction to home security systems"*, and *"An Introduction to automated safety systems"*. Be careful about using articles though.

Comment: @AIQ  Thank you very much.